# RecyclerView onBindViewHolder position not as expected

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I know this problem has being asked numerous times relating to ListViews, However I have never been able to understand the solution truly. I am aware that the position parameter of onBindViewHolder() in RecyclerViewAdapter is similar to the position parameter in listAdapter getView(). I also am aware that the position is only relative to visible views. So how can I go about loading an Image for each row of the RecyclerView? The image may be different depending on position. The RecyclerView has a known number of rows (57)

I intend to have an array list of 'favourites'for example int[] fav = {2,6,30,40}. So if position equals one of these elements then ImageView sets one drawble, else it sets another.Could anyone help me with this?

At the moment position repeats itself and many extra rows are setting the drawable reserved for row IDs in the fav array

Thank You,

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends ...... {

private List<StockItemRow> stockItems;
private Context mContext;
private int[] favourites = {2,3};



RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List modelData) {
    if (modelData == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("modelData must not be null");
    }
    this.stockItems = modelData;
    this.mContext = context;
}


@Override
public ListItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(...)
{
    View itemView =     
    LayoutInflater.fromLayoutInflater.
    from(viewGroup.getContext()).
    inflate(R.layout.listitem_row, viewGroup, false);

    return new ListItemViewHolder(itemView);
}


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ListItemViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    StockItemRow stockModel = stockItems.get(position);

    for(int i = 0;i<favourites.length;i++) {
        if (position == favourites[i]) {
             viewHolder.star.setImageResource(R.drawable.star_pressed);

    }
 }

 @Override
 public int getItemCount() {
     return stockItems.size();
 }

public final static class ListItemViewHolder extends....  
   ImageView star;

   public ListItemViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        star= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.star);
   }
}
}
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:divider="@drawable/list_selector"

    android:dividerHeight="1dip"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I don't really understand what your question is.  Your code appears to accomplish what you are trying to do.  position in onBindViewHolder is relative to the entire dataset, not just the visible items (exactly as in listView)

Comment: The position is the actual position along the entire array; Not the visible position.

Comment: the star_pressed drawable is showing for more row positions then two and three

Comment: 9,10,16,17,23,24 etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Deev is correct: the position is the position within the adapter, not on screen.  The problem you are running into is because your `onBindViewHolder()` method is only handling the favorite case, but not the non-favorite case.  The `ViewHolder` pattern is used for efficiency and it's re-using views.  Change the code to be this:

```
int fav_res = R.drawable.star;
for(int i = 0;i<favourites.length;i++) {
    if (position == favourites[i]) {
        fav_res = R.drawable.star_presed;
        break;
    }
}

viewHolder.star.setImageResource(fav_res);
```

Comment: Doing this it seems only the last element of the favourites array has 'star_pressed'drawable

Comment: That did it. Thank you. Just out of curiosity was ListviewAdapter the same? did it's position in getView() refer to position within adapter? I'm sure I had some kind of problem with that before and thought it refered to position on screen.

Comment: Yes, the position handed to `getView()` in the `ListView`'s adapter is the adapter's position.  There's no way for the adapter to know how to map on screen position to its data set.  It is just responsible for knowing its data set; the view is what manages how it is displayed.